# Automatic deletion of indexes after 3 days

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

i want to create an ilm policy in ELK to rollover to index after specific condition and delete indexes after 3 days. it gets created but it never rollovers gto the new index and it does not put index in delete phase.

i want index size of maximum of 1 gb but it goes beyond that even after specifying. it even shows 1 gb in setting but never applies.

Comment: Can you show your ILM policy definition as well as your index template definition?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

There are 2 conditions for size that could trigger a rollover

- `max_size` when the sum of all primary shard of an index reach this limit rollover
- `max_primary_shard_size` when a primary shard reach the limit rollover

Could it be that you confused one for the other ?

## Internals of ILM

Also, those condition are check every now and then.
[By default every 10 minutes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference//current/ilm-settings.html), so it is expected to have shard that are more than the limit.

You can tweak how often those condition are check by changing the value of `indices.lifecycle.poll_interval`.

But be warned setting it too low will put some strain on your cluster.

## To Debug

Also, having you ILM stuck happens from time to time to investigate why, you could be using the api [ILM explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-explain-lifecycle.html)

```json
GET my-index-000001/_ilm/explain
```

This could help you identify issues with your setup.

## Solution

From what I understand here is a policy that should work for your needs.

```json
PUT _ilm/policy/delete-3d-over-1g-ilm-policy
{
  "policy": {
    "phases": {
      "hot": {
        "actions": {
          "rollover": {
            "max_size": "1gb"
          }
        }
      },
      "delete": {
        "min_age": "3d",
        "actions": {
          "delete": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```